# Where can I find a 9mm x 26thread axle nut?

Tags: maintenance, parts

I have a Gravity Swift 2 that I got off Bikesdirect.  Somehow I lost the left front axle nut.  I have been to two LBSs and neither of them have (or have even seen) an axle nut this size.  I e-mailed the company and searched on Google but haven't gotten a response back yet.

- Is there anywhere to find a nut with these specs?
- If I can't find this nut, will I have to replace the wheel(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://www.bikepartsplace.com/brands/formula/) they sell "Formula" hubs, which are the ones you should have. Dropping a message and asking for replacement nuts won't do any harm. Otherwise you could buy a whole new hub and cannibalize the nut from it. It is certainly cheaper and easier than either buying a whole new wheel or (Holy spanner spare us) replacing the whole hub.

Answering to your second point. Let's assume you cannot find the correct nut. If you *have* (or you *want*) experience in replacing wheels' axles AND if you have the correct tools (cone spanners 13, 15 and 17mm, spanners 15mm and 17mm, a vice, grease) then it is certainly worth looking for a replacement axle. You should be able to find one quite easily.

Good luck anyways!

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out are your local hardware store.  They tend to have much more exotic parts and have huge catalogs of parts they can order from.

Comment: Actually, Ace Hardware was the first place I went to, and they didn't have anything either. Thanks though!

Comment: You might want to check out a few other stores. Or even see if there's professional hardware supply store in your area.  There's one in my area that has endless shelves full of different types of hardware. Also they seem to stock them on amazon (http://www.amazon.com/Campagnolo-Track-26tpi-Front-Each/dp/B001GSMU6C) but those are quite expensive. You should be able to find a generic brand for cheaper.  Most of the available nuts seem to be 9mm x 1mm thread pitch. which may just be close enough to fit. 1 mm gives you 25.4 tpi  (http://www.amazon.com/Halo-Alloy-axle-nuts-black/dp/B007Z1TBUM/)

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell whether you are talking about the nut that sits on the outside of the forks or on the inside (that locks against the cones to keep the hub together).

If you can make it to any bike shop they should be able to hook you up with the missing nut.

If you absolutely must order online, amazon probably has something for both: [Track Nut](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003B6MK30) or [Lock Nut](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006EPP6Z4)

Comment: It is indeed a [track nut](http://imgur.com/hmWKf.jpg).  I'm reluctant to buy the one on Amazon, since it doesn't specify the thread count, but I might as well since it is rather cheap. Thanks